# How do I iterate the SciPy Peak-finding algorithm over each column of a 2D array?

Tags: arrays, numpy, indexing, scipy, signal-processing

I am trying to count peaks in a signal. The signal comes from an image stack, with 180 images (1Hz imaging). In each stack, there are roughly 20-100 objects (cells) that I segment, and create a 2D NumPy array from (with shape e.g. [number of cells x 180 seconds].

I would like to use the SciPy peak counting algorithm, and plot peaks on the trace of my 2D array (delta F/F for those interested).

The problem is that, as far as I understand, this function expects a 1D array, and I have a 2D array.

So I tried flattening the 2D array into 1D, and counting those peaks - however, as each column in my array corresponds to a cell, when I flatten the array, there will be spurious 'peaks' added as the now 1D trace switches between cells.

Could I use a for loop to get the find_peaks function to iterate over each column in my 2D array, thus negating the need to reshape the array? I.e. access the 2D array by column, appearing as a 1D array for the find_peaks function?

What I tried:

My 2D array is 'smooth_signal'. It's shape is 15x180. Each column is one cell, with one signal trace over 180 seconds.

```
from scipy.signal import find_peaks 

peaks = np.zeros_like(smooth_signal)
for i in range(smooth_signal):
    peaks[:, i], _ = find_peaks(smooth_signal[:, i], height=1.2)
np.savetxt("peaks.csv", peaks, delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for-loop is the correct way to go. You have a 2D-array, yes, but if you loop through it you'll get a 1D-array each iteration. With these slight changes you should be fine:

```py
from scipy.signal import find_peaks 

peaks = []  # just go with an empty list here and append your results to it

for i in range(len(smooth_signal)):  # you forgot the len()
    peaks_in_one_trace, _ = find_peaks(smooth_signal[:, i], height=1.2)
    peaks.append(peaks_in_one_trace)
np.savetxt("peaks.csv", peaks, delimiter=',')
```

For style points a less understandable one-liner:

```py
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
peaks = [find_peaks(trace, height=1.2)[0] for trace in smooth_signal]
np.savetxt("peaks.csv", peaks, delimiter=',')
```

Let me know how it turns out.